# efficient way to iterate list?

Tags: python, list, word2vec

I am trying to find the duplicated words in google word2vec, for example, in word2vec, there are two word embeddings for 'Hello' and 'hello'. Here is my code, it's simple but not efficient.

```
def load_w2v():
openfile = '../Pretrained/word2vec/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(openfile, binary=True)
return model.vocab.keys()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pre_trained_words = load_w2v()
    ready_have = []
    duplicated_words = []
    for word in pre_trained_words:
        if word.lower() not in ready_have:
            ready_have.append(word.lower())
        else:
            duplicated_words.append(word)
            continue
```

However, as the pre-trained google word2vec has 3 million words, my computer has been runing for 18 hours and not finish, so I was wondering is there some effiencient way to get the duplicated words?

Comment: Are you convinced it's an efficiency problem, or maybe you fall into an infinite loop. Have you debugged the process?

Comment: Please define the duplicate. "Hello" and "hello" are duplicates, but is also "hello" occuring two or more times a duplicate?

Answer (score 4):

Your `in` membership tests on the `read_have` are O(N) time complexity each call so it's not surprising the approach is slow. You could speed this up by simply making `ready_have` a set and using `ready_have.add(word.lower())` (assuming the order of `read_have` is not important), or it might be cleaner to use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

my_counter = Counter(word.lower() for word in load_w2v())
ready_have, duplicated_words = [], []
for word, count in my_counter.items():
    read_have.append(word)
    if count != 1:
        duplicated_words.append(word)
```

Note I'm assuming for the `Counter` solution you only want to append each duplicated word once, although this could trivially be changed.

Comment: I'd like to suggest a generator expression `lower_case_words = (...)` to save several megabytes of memory.

Comment: @VPfB Agreed, in fact I just fed that to `Counter` directly thanks

Comment: Thx so much, it really helps and can finish in 5 mins